# Adding MBContactPickerView to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

Can anyone please help me out how to add a `MBContactPickerView` to `UITableViewCell`.

We are instantiating the `MBPickerView` with some dimensions and adding that instance to `UITableViewCell` using
`[cell.contentView addSubView:_mbContactPickerView];`

But, no result. Please reply me with some working example.

Thanks in advance,
prodeveloper.

Comment: What's wrong exactly? Could you show more code/screenshots?